# how to get the x values from the sorted 'y' array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array

i have a x,y dataset. It looks like this:

```
 var x = ['Test', 'Test2', 'Test3']
 var y = [0, 80, 20]
```

First Step I order it descending:

```
y.sort(function(a,b) {return b - a}))
```

then this came out:

```
console.log(y) // var y = [80, 20, 0]
```

Now my problem is, that I need also the x ordered by the y values (sorry for my English)!!

```
y: 80 -> x: Test2, y: 20 -> x: Test3, y:0 -> x: Test0
```

But I don't know how to do that. If I map then it map the x to y values in wrong order. It would be very kind if you can help me.

Comment: You can create an object from your dataset and sort based on y value.

Comment: Hello, could you post an example, since I am really a beginner in Javascript. Thanks

Comment: Please check the duplicate

Comment: @fau2019: const res=[];
    for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        const ob = {'x':x[i],
        'y':y[i]}; res.push(ob);}
        res.sort(function(a,b) {return b.y - a.y});